# Buscar en un JSON de arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este modelo de `JSON`

```
  pueblos = [
  {
    "id_ciudad": 10,
    "km": "124",
    "pueblos": [
      {
        "id_pueblo": 12,
        "km": "22",
        "pobllcion": 22
      },
      {
        "id_pueblo": 23,
        "km": "11",
        "pobllcion": 12
      },
      {
        "id_pueblo": 24,
        "km": "55",
        "pobllcion": 6
      }
    ]
  }
```

Necesito obtener el id de la ciudad cuyo id_pueblo sea 12 , es decir el primer item del array de Objectos.

estoy intentado algo asi, pero sin exito

```
let pueblo= listaPueblos.find(x => x.pueblos.id_pueblo == 12);
```

No quisiera usar un bucle `for()`, me gustaría hacerlo con los métodos de `JavaScript`, como el `.find()`

Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas añadir un `.find` sobre la propiedad `pueblos` de cada "ciudad".

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let listaPueblos = [{
  "id_ciudad": 10,
  "km": "124",
  "pueblos": [{
      "id_pueblo": 12, "km": "22", "pobllcion": 22
    },{
      "id_pueblo": 23, "km": "11", "pobllcion": 12
    },{
      "id_pueblo": 24, "km": "55", "pobllcion": 6
    }
  ]
}, {
  "id_ciudad": 12,
  "km": "124",
  "pueblos": [{
      "id_pueblo": 13, "km": "22", "pobllcion": 22
    }
  ]
}]

let pueblo = listaPueblos.find(x => x.pueblos.find(y => y.id_pueblo == 12));
console.log(pueblo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```js
listaPueblos = [
  {
    "id_ciudad": 10,
    "km": "124",
    "pueblo": {
      "id_pueblo": 12,
      "km": "22",
      "poblacion": 22
    }
  },
  {
    "id_ciudad": 11,
    "km": "245",
    "pueblo": {
      "id_pueblo": 13,
      "km": "55",
      "poblacion": 13
    }
  }
];


const result = listaPueblos.filter(obj => obj.pueblo.id_pueblo == 12);

console.log(result[0].id_ciudad);
```

Comment: había un error en Json en mi pregunta  ,te pido disculpas

Comment: Nada!!! encantados de ayudarte!"!!

Answer (score 0):

El código que tienes parece funcionar correctamente.

```js
listaPueblos = [
  {
    "id_ciudad": 10,
    "km": "124",
    "pueblo": {
      "id_pueblo": 12,
      "km": "22",
      "poblacion": 22
    }
  },
  {
    "id_ciudad": 11,
    "km": "245",
    "pueblo": {
      "id_pueblo": 13,
      "km": "55",
      "poblacion": 13
    }
  }
]

let pueblo = listaPueblos.find(x => x.pueblo.id_pueblo == 12);
console.log(pueblo.id_ciudad);
```

La variable `pueblo` almacena el array de la coincidencia, por lo que solo deberás hacer `pueblo.id_ciudad` para obtener el valor del campo.

Comment: había un error en Json en mi pregunta  ,te pido disculpas